# Is the big integer implementation in the num crate slow?

Tags: performance, rust, performance-testing, biginteger

I implemented the Miller-Rabin Strong Pseudoprime Test in Rust using `BigUint` to support arbitrary large primes. To run through the numbers between 5 and 10^6, it took about 40s with `cargo run --release`.

I implemented the same algorithm with Java's `BigInteger` and the same test took 10s to finish. Rust appears to be 4 times slower. I assume this is caused by the implementation of `num::bigint`.

Is this just the current state of `num::bigint`, or can anyone spot any obvious improvement in my code? (Mainly about how I used the language. Regardless whether my implementation of the algorithm is good or bad, it is almost implemented exactly the same in both languages - so does not cause the difference in performance.)

I did notice there are lots of `clone()` required, due to Rust's ownership model, that could well impact the speed to some level. But I guess there is no way around that, am I right?

Here is the code:

```
extern crate rand;
extern crate num;
extern crate core;
extern crate time;

use std::time::{Duration};
use time::{now, Tm};

use rand::Rng;
use num::{Zero, One};
use num::bigint::{RandBigInt, BigUint, ToBigUint};
use num::traits::{ToPrimitive};
use num::integer::Integer;
use core::ops::{Add, Sub, Mul, Div, Rem, Shr};

fn find_r_and_d(i: BigUint) -> (u64, BigUint) {
    let mut d = i;
    let mut r = 0;
    loop {
        if d.clone().rem(&2u64.to_biguint().unwrap()) == Zero::zero() {
            d = d.shr(1usize);
            r = r + 1;
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }
    return (r, d);
}

fn might_be_prime(n: &BigUint) -> bool {
    let nsub1 = n.sub(1u64.to_biguint().unwrap());
    let two = 2u64.to_biguint().unwrap();

    let (r, d) = find_r_and_d(nsub1.clone());
    'WitnessLoop: for kk in 0..6u64 {
        let a = rand::thread_rng().gen_biguint_range(&two, &nsub1);
        let mut x = mod_exp(&a, &d, &n);
        if x == 1u64.to_biguint().unwrap() || x == nsub1 {
            continue;
        }
        for rr in 1..r {
            x = x.clone().mul(x.clone()).rem(n);
            if x == 1u64.to_biguint().unwrap() {
                return false;
            } else if x == nsub1 {
                continue 'WitnessLoop;
            } 
        }
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

fn mod_exp(base: &BigUint, exponent: &BigUint, modulus: &BigUint) -> BigUint {
    let one = 1u64.to_biguint().unwrap();
    let mut result = one.clone();
    let mut base_clone = base.clone();
    let mut exponent_clone = exponent.clone();

    while exponent_clone > 0u64.to_biguint().unwrap() {
        if exponent_clone.clone() & one.clone() == one {
            result = result.mul(&base_clone).rem(modulus);
        } 
        base_clone = base_clone.clone().mul(base_clone).rem(modulus);
        exponent_clone = exponent_clone.shr(1usize);
    }
    return result;
}

fn main() {  
    let now1 = now();

    for n in 5u64..1_000_000u64 {
        let b = n.to_biguint().unwrap();
        if might_be_prime(&b) {
            println!("{}", n);
        }
    }

    let now2 = now();
    println!("{}", now2.to_timespec().sec - now1.to_timespec().sec);
}
```

Comment: Note: `core::ops` is re-exported as `std::ops`, so you need not import it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can remove most of the clones pretty easily. `BigUint` has all ops traits implemented also for operations with `&BigUint`, not just working with values. With that, it becomes faster but still about half as fast as Java...

Also (not related to performance, just readability) you don't need to use `add`, `sub`, `mul` and `shr` explicitly; they override the regular `+`, `-`, `*` and `>>` operators.

For instance you could rewrite `might_be_prime` and `mod_exp` like this, which already gives a good speedup on my machine (from 40 to 24sec on avg):

```
fn might_be_prime(n: &BigUint) -> bool {
    let one = BigUint::one();
    let nsub1 = n - &one;
    let two = BigUint::new(vec![2]);
    let mut rng = rand::thread_rng();

    let (r, mut d) = find_r_and_d(nsub1.clone());
    let mut x;
    let mut a: BigUint;
    'WitnessLoop: for kk in 0..6u64 {
        a = rng.gen_biguint_range(&two, &nsub1);
        x = mod_exp(&mut a, &mut d, &n);
        if &x == &one || x == nsub1 {
            continue;
        }
        for rr in 1..r {
            x = (&x * &x) % n;
            if &x == &one {
                return false;
            } else if x == nsub1 {
                continue 'WitnessLoop;
            } 
        }
        return false;
    }
    true
}

fn mod_exp(base: &mut BigUint, exponent: &mut BigUint, modulus: &BigUint) -> BigUint {
    let one = BigUint::one();
    let zero = BigUint::zero();
    let mut result = BigUint::one();

    while &*exponent > &zero {
        if &*exponent & &one == one {
           result = (result * &*base) % modulus;
        }
        *base = (&*base * &*base) % modulus;
        *exponent = &*exponent >> 1usize;
    }
    result
}
```

Note that I've moved the println! out of the timing, so that we're not benchmarking IO.

```
fn main() {  
    let now1 = now();

    let v = (5u64..1_000_000u64)
        .filter_map(|n| n.to_biguint())
        .filter(|n| might_be_prime(&n))
        .collect::<Vec<BigUint>>();

    let now2 = now();
    for n in v {
        println!("{}", n);
    }
    println!("time spent seconds: {}", now2.to_timespec().sec - now1.to_timespec().sec);
}
```

Comment: @peterpeiguo I tested quickly on the same machine (but it's Windows). I'll try benchmarking more properly later. It would be best to remove the printing of the list from the benchmark, to make sure IO is not the actual bottleneck

Comment: true, I can comment out the printing from both rust and java and re-benchmark. In all test, I did redirect all printing to a file, so at least was not printing to the screen, which is super slow. I am on windows too. I will dig this deeper later.

Comment: @PeterPeiGuo if you haven't seen it before, Rust has a [good built-in way to benchmark](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/benchmark-tests.html)

Comment: @PeterPeiGuo after benchmarking and checking the source code for BigUint I think this answer is almost all wrong. I wanted to revise it, but I don't like to change substantially an accepted answer... Could you please un-accept, so that others are not misdirected? I'll review it and you can decide if accepting or not (and in the meanwhile others might chime in and provide a better answer too)

Comment: Done, Thanks for your most detailed analysis and that is the spirit!

Comment: By the way, just to share some info, I was going to try xxxassgin as others suggested, so I downloaded the unstable rust 1.8. It took 60+s for the baseline code to finish, which is 1.5* slow, and I dropped that idea.

Comment: @PeterPeiGuo yes that's one of the points I think I had overlooked... Looking at [how Add is implemented](https://github.com/rust-num/num/blob/master/src/bigint.rs#L760-L776) it's already reusing the first value (adding the second value to it and returning it again)

Comment: To be honest, I do not expect there is any way to speed up the code dramatically, I think that is just the current state of language. I still intend to accept this as the answer, for couple reasons: 1) after removing those calls of clone(), there was a 10% performance improvement; 2) the suggestion of using overloaded operators; 3) the meaningful discussion we had. But I will wait until you complete your planned update to your answer.